# Get/post to JSON RESTful web service with VB6

Tags: json, web-services, rest, vb6

Is there anyone know how to Get from or to post to a RESTful web service that replies with JSON?

for example, I want to call this url: www.web1.service.com/?apikey=111-222-333&param1=Adam&param2=Smith

and this RESTful web service will reply with JSON.

Thanks.

AE

Comment: Why cannot you just call it?

Comment: I want to build an application to do the call and get the data from the 3rd party RESTful web service that reply with JSON. Thanks.

Comment: Why cannot you just do that?

Comment: Do you know how? Please help me in that and I will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share a VB code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: (You need to add reference to Microsoft XML, v4.0) from Project->References...

```
Private Function urlLaunch(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim Ans As String
    Dim oHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP, sBuffer As String
    Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    oHTTP.Send
    sBuffer = oHTTP.responseText
    Set oHTTP = Nothing
    urlLaunch = sBuffer
End Function
```